# Can Dyalog user commands be invoked from code?

Tags: dyalog

My understanding is that generally one shouldn't want to do this, but my particular use case involves testing a custom user command, so being able to invoke something like `⎕SE.Foo 'mycmd my arguments'` would be quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, per [the documentation](https://docs.dyalog.com/latest/User%20Commands%20User%20Guide.pdf#page=11):

> This implementation means that application code can invoke user commands by calling `⎕SE.UCMD` directly.

In your case, it would be `⎕SE.UCMD 'mycmd my arguments'`